# I want to verify if argument value passed to a function is an instance of X

Tags: python

I want to make sure that some arguments are instance of a class.
Here is my code, is there a better approach?

```
class Object(object):

    @property
    def _attr_classes(self):
        return {'x': str, 'y': int}

    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __setattr__(self, attr_name, value):

        if attr_name in self._attr_classes:
            correct_instance = self._attr_classes[attr_name]
            if value and isinstance(value, correct_instance) is False:
                raise TypeError('Error for key argument: "{0}", value: "{1}" is not instance of "{2}"'.
                                format(attr_name, value, correct_instance))
        return super(Object, self).__setattr__(attr_name, value)
```

Comment: **Why** do you care about the *type* of `value`?  In duck-typed languages such as Python, that's a smell that hints at a design error in parts of the code you've not presented.

Comment: Also, in Python 3.x, you could use type hints and a static analyzer to check types at "compile" time (i.e. after having written the code, not at run time).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a subtle bug in your line `if value and isinstance(value, correct_instance) is False:`

First, you should not identity compare to `False`, just use `if value and not isinstance(value, correct_instance):`.

Now, what if value is a falsey value, for example consider trying to do `obj = Object(); obj.y = ""`. This will not raise a `TypeError`, because `""` is not a truthy value, so it will never get to the `isinstance` because of short-circuiting.

I'm not sure why you have it in there in the first place. Were you trying to protect against `None` values? If that is the case, use `if value is not None`. Here you want identity comparison (and not equality/truthiness).

As Peilonrayz said in the comments, this is mentioned at the end of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style-guide. It is worth a read and actually quite readable.

---

What is nice about your code is that it allows allowing multiple classes. `isinstance` takes a tuple of classes to check *or* a single class.
So you could use `{'x': str, 'y': (int, float)}` and it should still work.

Comment: It's quite funny that had OP followed PEP 8, under [Programming Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), then they wouldn't have the above bugs. (The second and last bullet points)

Comment: @Peilonrayz sorry i am new to programming and i didnt read PEP, looks like i should

Comment: @Baks You don't have to read *all* PEPs, just the mighty PEP8 (as well as [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) and [PEP343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), which are all just a whole lot of fun to read).